# What domain of AI do I need for this?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, supervised-learning

There's a database with a large amount of items (~500,000) each having an amount of properties (~20), identified by an integer. There are ~50,000 different properties.

I want to write a program that finds the best matches between items based on the items' properties. There's a metric available that defines how good a match is, but only some time after the match has been made. Just because two items share the same property doesn't mean it'll be a good match.
This program would have to learn from a set of already made matches (for each of which the metric is known) which groups of properties go together and make the best matches.

After the learning process it should be able to make the best matches for new items that partially have the same properties as the ones that were learned from well. Additionally, the program should learn from each match it makes as soon as the metric becomes available to improve itself.

How do I take this on? I'm not sure which domain of AI this falls in (hence the title), but I figured the program would start to classify items by their properties since that's how I'd do it manually...
What algorithm(s) should I certainly look into?

EDIT:
I thought of hopfield networks, where part or all of an item's properties would lead it to a category, but I'm not sure that works on this scale.

Comment: Are you basically trying to solve the Netflix Recommendation problem?

Comment: No not quite, but it does appear to show some resemblance. Apparently the winners had to publish their methods, so thanks for providing a good read.

Comment: Isnt this a supervisioned problem? since you already have some matches ? You cou try to used something like Naive-Bayes or even Decision trees that will create a classifier from the data you already have and evaluate the new data you want

Answer (score 0):

This is typical clustering problem in machine learning, there are Algorithms like K-means can help you. You can experiment with your data using Weka/Orange and choose which algorithms best suits to you. Once you determine right algorithms, you can do the same programatically.

Comment: That's an awfully high dimensional (50,000) and sparsely populated (500,000) space to be clustering in.  Especially when you don't know _a priori_ the number of clusters.

Comment: I looked into K-means, but I'm not quite sure how I would apply it on this  specific problem. @Novak suggested having a dimension for every property, but I think that's not maintainable. I thought of something along the lines of working with 20 dimensions, each vector containing the propertynumbers per item ordered by significance. That left me with how to devise a proper distance function for that and even more importantly, as Novak also brought up, I don't know how many clusters there will be. It does however seem to best fit clustering problems, so what that concerns your answer is helpful!

Comment: It occurs to me that if high dimensions are the problem, then some form of dimensionality reduction technique-- PCA, ICA, etc-- might help you out.  For clustering, the naive technique is to run multiple times with different cluster assumptions until you're not seeing much change.  The Swiss army knife (or maybe sledge hammer) is Bayesian non-parametrics.  That's a deep, dark rabbit hole to go down, though.